# Is it possible to configure the color of text/background in react without using CSS?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am trying to find out if it is possible to add/change colors using the .js file alone without utilizing .css on react?

Comment: You can use inline styling yes, but at the end of the day it's still CSS (technically).

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Check `styled-components` approach e.g. https://styled-components.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can use inline styles in react like this `<p style={{color: 'red, fontSize: '12px'}}>Lorem ipsum</p>`
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/inline-styling-with-react